# C++ Do operation on bits of a std::bitset

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-manipulation

I want to AND 4 4-bits of a std::bitset<16> with each other. I mean:

```
std::bitset<16> arr("1100 1100 1100 1100");
```

I want to AND these 4-bits array.

```
std::bitset<4> a;
```

a=     1100 & 1100 & 1100 & 1100

I want to do this in  the most efficient way. Not using for loops.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need a for loop for this, unless you don't need `bitset<16>` in earlier calculation, and somehow extract to 4 `bitset<4>` instead.

Comment: ok. How to do this with loop but in efficient way?

Comment: With 16 bits, no need to care about efficiency, unless this is a tight loop that needs to be executed many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so long as you know how many bits the target and source are you can do this.

```
std::bitset<16> arr("1100110011001100");
std::bitset<4> v (
    ((arr    ) & 
     (arr>>4 ) & 
     (arr>>8 ) & 
     (arr>>12)).to_ulong() 
     &   0x0f
);
```

Comment: what about doing same thing with 320-bits arr. it seems that overflow error accurs

Comment: if you have 320 bit bitset I would loop, with the offset increasing by 4 each time.

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortcut with slicing bitsets. Just work your way through the bits

```
a[0] = arr[0] & arr[4] & arr[8] & arr[12];
```

etc.

It can't take the computer long to check 16 bits, however you do it!

Comment: it just AND bit 0,4,8,12 with each other

Comment: @batistacori he means that you have to do that with each `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is:

```
unsigned long i = arr.to_ulong();
i = (i & (i >> 4) & (i >> 8) & (i >> 12)) & 0xf;
a = std::bitset<4>(i);
```